# PHP SQL JOIN - Adding secondary Field to results

Tags: php, sql, database, join, mysqli

I'm sure this is a simple one, but I cannot get this to work!

I have a table of Members 'Members', and a table of Trades 'Trades', and Members are associated with a trade using a relative ID. (Members: trade_id, Trades: id).

My code is as follows, which pulls in Members of certain Trade, and is working, BUT I have now introduced a new field in the Members Table, trade_id2, so they can be associated with more than one Trade.

Simply put, if this page has the ID '1' in the URL, I want to pull in any Members that have 1 in the trade_id field OR trade_id2 field.

How should I add this to the existing code?

```
$members_sql="SELECT Members.id, Members.display_name, Members.email, Members.phone_1, Members.phone_2, Members.sub_id, Trades.trade FROM Members 
        JOIN Trades ON Members.trade_id=Trades.id 
        WHERE Members.sub_id > 0 AND Members.active = 1 AND Members.trade_id=".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY Members.sub_id DESC, Members.display_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to associate a member with more than one trade, the proper way to solve this is to refactor your database to define a many-to-many relationship. You have to remove the `trade_id` field from the `Members` table and define a new table (you can call it `Members_Trade`) with both `trade_id` and `member_id` fields, each associated to the correspondent tables. That way you can add as many trades as you want to each member, and of course any trade can be associated with many members as well.

EDIT: Here's an example of an SQL query with aliased tables:

```
$sql = "SELECT m.id, m.display_name, m.email, m.phone_1, n.phone_2, m.sub_id, t1.trade, t2.trade 
    FROM Members m 
    JOIN Trades t1 ON m.trade_id = t1.id 
    JOIN Trades t2 ON m.trade_id = t2.id 
    WHERE m.sub_id > 0 AND m.active = 1 AND (t1.id = $_GET['id'] OR t2.id = $_GET['id'])"
```

Comment: Thanks José - Much appreciated.  I will only ever have 2 Trades, and so do you know how I'd be able to pull this info in without refactoring?

Comment: You could try aliasing the tables. Please see my updated answer. 
Remember this is just an example, you should never user raw $_GET variables directly in a quote, you should use parameterized queries or sanitize the variables first.

EDIT: I've removed the SQL from this comment and added to my answer instead for better readability.

Comment: Thanks, and I take it on the second join, m.trade_id should be ..trade_id2? (The name of the secondary trade field associated with a Member)